# How to copy a blob from one container to another in node using Storage SDK v10 for JavaScript

Tags: node.js, azure, copy, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is this possible?

I used to use `startCopyBlob` however, I am now transitioning to npm `@azure/storage-blob` and cannot find a way...

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check out [BlobURL.startCopyFromURL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/bloburl?view=azure-node-legacy#startcopyfromurl-aborter--string--iblobstartcopyfromurloptions-).

Also the latest Storage SDK release is v12.  Are there reasons that prevent you from using v12?